# can't get ROUGE score with pyrouge

Tags: python, text, summarization

I was carrying out an experiment on text summarization. After getting the decoded sentences and reference sentences, I used pyrouge to obtain the ROUGE score, the python code is as follows:

```
from pyrouge import Rouge155
r=Rouge155()
r.model_filename_pattern = '#ID#——reference.txt'
r.system_filename_pattern = '(\d+)_decoded.txt'
r.model_dir = '/home/test/reference'
r.system_dir = '/home/test/decoded'

rouge_results = r.convert_and_evaluate()
print rouge_results
output_dict = r.output_to_dict(output)
```

but it didn't seem to work, it reported a `subprocess.CalledProcessError` and

```
Illegal division by zero at /.../.../ROUGE/RELEASE-1.5.5/ROUGE-1.5.5.pl
```

Here's the specific error information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "rouge.py", line 28, in <module>
       rouge_results = r.convert_and_evaluate()
   File "/home/username/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyrouge-0.1.3.py2.7.egg/pyrouge/Rouge155.py", line 364, in convert_and_evaluate
       rouge_output = self.evaluate(system_id, rouge_args)
   File "/home/username/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyrouge-0.1.3.py2.7.egg/pyrouge/Rouge155.py", line 339, in evaluate
       rouge_output = check_output(command).decode("UTF-8")
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 574, in check_output
       raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '[u'/home/username/env/ROUGE/RELEASE-1.5.5/ROUGE-1.5.5.pl', '-e', '/home/username/env/ROUGE/RELEASE-1.5.5/data', '-c', '95','-2', '-1', '-U', '-r', '1000', '-n','4','-w','1.2','-a',u'-m', u' /tmp/tmpG9VKo9/rouge_conf.xml']' returned non-zero exit status 255
```

Has anyone come across this kind of issue? Appreciate any suggestion! Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include the full error as text instead of a screenshot of the error.

Comment: thanks! I've added the full error information:)

Answer (score 0):

I found that this issue was caused by the `<s>`and `</s>`in the reference sentences. I deleted these symbols and got the ROUGE score in the end.

Answer (score 0):

In general I found you have to remove from your summaries all the tags are like: `<something>`. In my case I used the following instruction to remove `<n>`:

```
summary.replace('<n>', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from line 2455 in the ROUGE-1.5.5.pl file.

$$score=wlcsWeightInverse($$hit/$$base,$weightFactor);

If some of the test files are empty or if there are other strange characters, you will get this error.

A simple workaround if you don't want to check all the test files is to add an exception handler.

```
use Error ':try';
try{
  $$score=wlcsWeightInverse($$hit/$$base,$weightFactor);
} catch Error::Simple with {
  my $err = shift;
  print "ERROR: $err";
};
```